# VBA - How to pass the range selected to TextBox as a reference?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

So far I have a small UserForm that contains a TextBox(TextBox1) and Button(BtnRng).

What I would like is to insert a range in to the TextBox by using a range selector. So far I have managed to create an InputBox with a type value of 8. However, I am unable to figure out how to pass the range that is selected in to the TextBox as a reference.

For example, If I select the Range A1 to A10, the InputBox correctly displays "$A$1:$A$10". But what I then want is that reference to be placed in to the TextBox. It is this part I am unable to figure out. At the moment it wants to place the value of the cells selected in the range in to the text box.

This is the code I have so far:

```
Private Sub BtnRng_Click()
Dim ThisRng As String
ThisRng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Get Range", Type:=8)
TextBox1.Text = ThisRng
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function `InputBox` with parameter `Type = 8` returns object of `Range` class (not `String`).

That is why you cannot put it directly into text box. First you need to use its `Address` property to obtain its address.

```
Private Sub BtnRng_Click()
    Dim ThisRng As Excel.Range

    Set ThisRng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Get Range", Type:=8)
    TextBox1.Text = ThisRng.Address        
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect! Can't believe I missed that!

Comment: Concise and to the point but you should also handle the Cancel: `On Error Resume Next` and `If Not ThisRng Is Nothing Then ...`